# Adding probability javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array  `var data = ['win', 'lose', 'draw']`. What I want is that 50% of the times I want win 30% of times I want lose and 20% times I want draw as the outcome. How can I apply this using javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by "adding probability" to the app?

Comment: I mean that there should be a probability of what is being selected in the end like label 1 should have a probability of .5

Answer (score 0):

You need a probability-based random number generator.

Here's one way to do it. Use a frequency array and assign more frequency to the candidate you want more probability of

```
function findRandom(arr, freq,  n) {
    // Create and fill prefix array
    let prefix= [];
    let i;
    prefix[0] = freq[0];
    for (i = 1; i < n; ++i)
        prefix[i] = prefix[i - 1] + freq[i];
 
    // prefix[n-1] is sum of all frequencies.
    // Generate a random number with
    // value from 1 to this sum
    let r = Math.floor((Math.random()* prefix[n - 1])) + 1;
 
    // Find index of ceiling of r in prefix array
    let indexc = findCeil(prefix, r, 0, n - 1);
    return arr[indexc];
}

function findCeil(arr, r, l, h){
    let mid;
    while (l < h)
    {
        mid = l + ((h - l) >> 1); // Same as mid = (l+h)/2
        (r > arr[mid]) ? (l = mid + 1) : (h = mid);
    }
    return (arr[l] >= r) ? l : -1;
}
 
// Driver code
let data = ["win","lose","draw"];
let freq = [50,30,20];
let n = data.length;
let i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  console.log(findRandom(data, freq, n));
```

Now, the output would be according to the assigned frequency but for fewer runs(run the function 10 times) the probability might not look precisely according to the assigned frequency

Here's the output of the 10 times call using the for loop above:

```
win
lose
win
win
win
draw
win
win
lose
draw
```